# Drupal Shopping cart sql error

Tags: sql, drupal-6, runtime-error, ubercart

Keep getting an error within the drupal log and do not under stand why. Can someone help me out? FYI I have a shopping cart on the website. Pipettes.com. I've also attached a screenshot

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Message error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 query: SELECT `id`, `price` FROM wb_uc_cart_items WHERE `cart_id` = '00df18eef923efe7bc180f0307e713e4' AND `snid` = 31469 AND `status` = 'new' AND `discounted` = 'yes' ORDER BY `price` ASC LIMIT in /mnt/ebs/apache2/vhosts/pipettes.com/html/sites/all/modules/indigo_import/indigo_import.module on line 623.

indigo_import.module on line 623

```
621         $sql_updates = array();
622
623         $result = db_query($sql);
624         while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
625
626                 $sql_updates[] = "UPDATE {wb_uc_cart_items}
627                 SET `status` = 'd'
628                 WHERE `id` = " . $row->id . " AND `discounted` = 'yes' AND `status` = 'new' LIMIT $s_discount_qty;";
629                 $dx++;
630
631                 if($snode->field_discounted_prices[0]['value']) {
632                         $this_total_discount += ($row->price - $snode->field_discounted_prices[0]['value']);
633                 } elseif($snode->field_discounted_percentage[0]['value']) {
634                         $this_total_discount += (($snode->field_discounted_percentage[0]['value'] / 100) * $row->price);
635                 }
636
637         }
```

[image: Screen shot of error in drupal log]

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of $s_discount_qty? It appears that the SQL statement in your log has a LIMIT  clause without a following value. Are you able to execute the SQL statement via the mysql command line interface? IE: is it valid?